# Combined index performance

Tags: database, performance

Suppose I have a table with 10 columns (no matter data-types), and I need to perform inserts in this table. But, as contraints, all rows must be differents and 2 rows are equal only if they have the same values in the same columns (obviate id columns).

For example

Equal:
(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

Different:
(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and (0,1,2,0,4,5,6,7,8,9)

The only solution I know it's to create a combined index with all columns but I'm worry about performace (could be more columns).
My question is how much does this index affect the performace?
Of course, I would like to know other solutions if exists.

Comment: Try your method. If it is too slow you can ask about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029921/using-multi-column-unique-indexes-vs-single-hashed-column

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your RDBMS etc. - but no, a unique index over several columns should not have any significant performance issues. It helps if you can have the "left most" columns in your index (i.e. the first ones in your "create index" statement) be the most unique ones.

As the link in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029921/using-multi-column-unique-indexes-vs-single-hashed-column) suggests, the alternative is to create a hash of your column values, and create a unique index on that one hashed column.

I'd write a performance test suite to decide whether the "unique index across multiple columns" solution is fast enough, because all the alternatives are likely to be a lot of work, and may be slower.